# WebSphere WorkManager Cluster Double Execution of the Job

Tags: asynchronous, websphere, ejb-3.0, workmanagers

I have an Application deployed on WebSphere 8.5 with Java 1.7.1, defined with a cluster of 2 nodes.
In this application there is an EJB that, through a work manager submit an Async Job.

The problem is that on WAS 8.5 the Job is executed two times on both node of the cluster. In WAS 6.1 this did not happen.

The work is submitted by an Alarm Manager. Below the code extracted:

```
WorkManager wm = serviceLocator.getWorkManager("NameOfCustomWorkManager");            
AsynchScope scope = wm.findAsynchScope("scopeName");

if (scope == null) 
    scope = wm.createAsynchScope("scopeName");

AlarmManager alarmManager = scope.getAlarmManager();        

alarmManager.create(listener, "Alarm Context Info", (int) (DateUtils.getNextTime(nextTime) - System.currentTimeMillis()));  --Fired on a certain hours     

logger.info("Alarm fired.");
```

Somebody know if on was 8.5 there are additional configuration to avoid the problem described?

Answer (score 0):

WorkManager in WebSphere Application Server, regardless of which version, does not have and has never had the ability to operate or coordinate across remote JVMs.  The designed behavior of the WorkManager is that it is only able to run the work that you submit on the same JVM from where you submitted the work, and that it has no awareness of duplicate work that you submit from a different JVM and no mechanism for coordinating work across JVMs.  The same is true of AlarmManager instances that you obtain from the WorkManager.  (WebSphere Application Server actually has a way of accomplishing the above, which is the Scheduler, but the above code is not using that).  Could it be possible that some earlier logic in the application that is impacted by the version change could be causing the Alarm to be created on both members now, whereas previously it would have only been created on one?